# Angular 2 Select Dropdown not Binding after Default value provided

Tags: javascript, html, angular

This is my Angular 2 Code:

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="wrapupData.assignToEmployee">
  <option value="" disabled>Choose Status</option>
    <option *ngFor="let emp of masterWrapupLov.employeeList" 
       [value]='emp.id'>{{emp?.name}}</option>
</select>
```

where `wrapupData.assignToEmployee` is a string, `masterWrapupLov.employeeList` is an array of Objects comprising `id: string` and `name: string`.

This code works perfectly fine selecting the option to make it reflect in the `wrapupData.assignToEmployee` model.

What I wanted to achieve is to select a default option when loading the DOM and update the model if the option is changed. I tried using `[selected]` comparing `emp.id` with the value I wanted to select, it did work in the UI but is not getting binded with the model as and when I change it. I tried using a default value using the model, that too is not working as it should and is not getting binded after the first default binding. I don't know if I'm clear enough, but I tried many methods that people have already suggested but nothing seems to work.

Comment: On the backend you need to also set it up so that the default value for your `ngModel` is that of the initial `emp.id`.

Comment: Actually, I do not know what the issue previously was, I reset my code and did what you said and it worked. I tried it previously though it didn't work then, but now it seems to be working like a gem.

Comment: Shouldn't the ngfor be on the select?

Comment: Code is weird. Glad it's working now!